# Why does spring use ioc and di?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I'm new to spring 5 and my question is why does spring use DI and IOC? I mean why do we have to write the beans in an XML (legacy) and then create it where we need it? Why don't we use one method instead that gives us that object, until we want to use this complex mechanism that happens in the spring container?

And another question is, does not reading XML slow down the program? Because we are reading from the hard disk anyway.

**Note**: It is true that we can use annotations, but for now I want to ask a question about reading from xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring IoC Container is the core of Spring Framework. It creates the objects, configures and assembles their dependencies, manages their entire life cycle. The Container uses Dependency Injection(DI) to manage the components that make up the application. It gets the information about the objects from a configuration file(XML) or Java Code or Java Annotations and Java POJO class. These objects are called Beans. Since the Controlling of Java objects and their lifecycle is not done by the developers, hence the name Inversion Of Control.
More on link [HERE](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/spring-ioc-container/#:%7E:text=Spring%20IoC%20Container%20is%20the,that%20make%20up%20the%20application.)

As for your first part of the question.

> why does spring use DI

To allow the developer to keep his code loose, and not entagle classes, it keeps your code clean.
In object oriented design, the amount of coupling refers to how much the design of one class depends on the design of another class. In other words, how often do changes in class A force related changes in class B? Tight coupling means the two classes often change together, loose coupling means they are mostly independent. In general, loose coupling is recommended because it's easier to test and maintain.

[You may find this paper by Martin Fowler (PDF) helpful.](https://martinfowler.com/ieeeSoftware/coupling.pdf)

> I mean why do we have to write the beans in an XML (legacy) and then create it where we need it

Note: We write the bean in XML and it is created when application starts when it looks at bean defintion, techinally you are never creating a bean, you are fetching only created bean from Spring Container(IOC) that Spring created for you when you started your application.

We are writing bean blueprint, or just bean, so that it can be constructed, placed in the Spring Container when the application starts, and then we have it at our disposal that we can fetch it using getBean method.
The whole point of "why", is because by default all beans are scoped as singleton, that means, when you fetch a bean, and do with it whatever you want, you do not worry about memory or anything, Spring takes care of the beans for you if they are scoped as a Singleton.

Second question:

> And another question is, does not reading XML slow down the program? Because we are reading from the hard disk anyway.

There is no difference in performance between annotation or XML, it is just a different approach, I am not sure what you mean by "reading from hard disk", but one way or another you will have to configure your application, yes, many forums prefer to run away from XML, but in my honest opinion the only reason for that is because when you write a bad configuration in XML it is lot harder to find it compared to configuration in Java that will throw an exception.
XML, application.properties files require a redeployment of the application, while annotation and java configuration require recompilation of your project, so both of them have "flaws", but it is normal and quite understandable to me.

But in the end I believe that it is a matter of preference, I know personally quite a few people that combine annotations with XML configuration and they know lot more about Spring compared to me.

So in summary, it is pain to write beans and their configuration, same as you can write a class with methods without creating an interface for it since the result will be the same, but it will help you in the long run since you do not have to worry about memory or if you destroyed that bean or if you did not.

It would be nice that you read about

[1.Lazy initialization of beans](https://www.imperva.com/learn/performance/lazy-loading/#:%7E:text=While%20lazy%20loading%20delays%20the,entities%20referenced%20by%20a%20resource.)

[2.Eager initialization of beans](https://www.imperva.com/learn/performance/lazy-loading/#:%7E:text=While%20lazy%20loading%20delays%20the,entities%20referenced%20by%20a%20resource.)

[3.Singleton scope of beans](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes)

[4.Prototype scope of beans](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes)